# Store the shortest path DFS

Tags: c, graph, depth-first-search, path-finding

I created a graph with adjacency lists and use the DFS algorithm to find the shortest path.
However I'm only able to print out where the program goes in the graph but I don't get how I could save the shortest path.
Here the code

```
int path[1000];
int j = 0;


t_graph         *create_graph(int v)                                                                      
{                                                                                                         
  int           i = 0;                                                                                        
  t_graph       *graph;                                                                                   

  if ((graph = malloc(sizeof(*graph))) == NULL)                                                           
    return (NULL);                                                                                        
  graph->v = v;                                                                                           
  if ((graph->arr = malloc(sizeof(t_list) * v)) == NULL)                                                  
    return (NULL);                                                                                        
  while (i < v)                                                                                           
    {                                                                                                     
      graph->arr[i].visited = 0;                                                                          
      graph->arr[i++].head = NULL;                                                                        
    }                                                                                                     
  return (graph);                                                                                         
} 


int find_path(t_graph *graph, int nb, int end)
{
 t_node *node;
 int i;

 i = 0;
 graph->arr[nb].visited = 1;
 path[j++] = nb;
 while (node)
   {
    if (node->nb == end)
      {
        path[j++] = node->nb;
        while (i < j)
          {
            printf("%d -> ", path[i++]);
          }
        printf("\n");
        j--;
      }
    if (graph->arr[node->nb].visited == 0)
      find_path(graph, node->nb, end);
    node = node->next;
   }
   j--;
}
```

I modify my code by adding 2 times j-- to do like a backtracking in my array, it works better but i have a few bugs.
For example I want to go from 0 to 5, it will give me 1-2-3-4-5 but also 1-2-3-4-5-6-5.
Do you have any idea on how to resolve this ?

So I tried to store the path in an array and if the neighbor is the end, I print this array, but it doesn't work.
I think it's because I don't go back in the array if the path isn't good and I don't handle well the recursive if we found the path.

Here how I call the function also

```
find_path(graph, 0, 7);
```

I start at the node n°0 and want to go to the node n°7.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code in your question has several problems that make it difficult to answer your question (definition of `t_graph` and `t_node` is missing, in `find_path` the `node` is used before it has been initialized).